# PHPmailer parseAddresses - How to get rid of "notice" messages

Tags: phpmailer

I'm trying to get rid of the following message in one of my scripts when using the PHPmailer parseAddresses function:

**Notice: Unknown: Must use comma to separate addresses: xxx (errflg=3) in Unknown on line 0**

```
$mailer = new PHPMailer(true);
try {
    $a = $mailer->parseAddresses('aaa@aaa.aaa xxx');
}
finally {
    ...
}
```

I'm using PHP 7.0.8 with the following error handling presets:

```
declare(strict_types = 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'stdout');
```

I know that I can just stop the errors from being displayed but this doesn't seem to be the proper way to do. And of course I know that the provided email addresses in my example are not correct...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're complaining about: it's telling you you have malformed input when you provide malformed input! The way to avoid the error is not to pass in malformed input!

As the error says, it's expecting one or more addresses in comma-delimited RFC822 format (not what you provided), which might be something like:

```
xxx <aaa@aaa.aaa>, yyy <bbb@aaa.aaa>
```

If you don't provide data in that format, it will complain, as you're seeing. This is covered [in the docs](http://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.html#method_parseAddresses) on the `parseAddress` method.

Are you expecting it to do something else?

Comment: As I mentioned in my question - I know that the input is not correct, but how can I capture the warning message before it is shown to the user? The try / catch approach isn't working. And I don't just want to "suppress" errors or warnings.

Comment: The solution is to make sure it's in the right format before you pass it in. The purpose of `parseAddresses` is to break a valid RFC822 address line into an array of addresses. If that's not what you want to do, don't use it.

Comment: Thank you. And to check if the addresses are in the right format in advance I use...parseAddresses?

Comment: Some other `extract_email_addresses_from_a_random_string()` function? Validating full RFC822 is not at all easy. Pull requests welcome. The usual application for `parseAddresses` is to break out the value part of a "to" header line from an existing email message that has been received. If you're getting them from some other source that's unlikely to be compliant, or is in some other random format, filter them yourself.

Comment: Yes, @synchro, I know that this is not easy. It would nonetheless be nice to be able to switch-off or redirect the warning messages thrown by parseAddresses if there are any malformatted addresses in the given string.

Answer (score 0):

PHPMailer writes notices to output, so you could start an output buffer and just flush it after your call.  Something like:

```
$mailer = new PHPMailer(true);
try {
    ob_start();
    $a = $mailer->parseAddresses('aaa@aaa.aaa xxx');
    //$notices = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
}
finally {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to deal with the same issues. Simply created a homemade solution that does mostly the same thing in a more flexible way. For anyone that is interested:

```
/**
 * split_addresses Split a list of email addresses with potential validation
 *          Similar concept as PHPMailer->parseAddresses, but more forgiving
 * @param $list - a list of comma delimited email addresses in simple or RFC822 format
 * @param $default_name an optional name to add if not present
 * @param $validate logical var to indicate to only accept validated emails
 * @author Jacques Amar
 * @copyright 2019 Amar Micro Inc.
 */

function split_addresses($list, $default_name='', $validate=true) {
    $valid_arr = [];
    if (empty($list)) { return $valid_arr; }
    $split_arr = preg_split('/\s*,\s*/', $list);
    foreach ($split_arr as $email_candidate) {
        // Validate email_candidate if the form "first last <adrs@email.com>"
        $actual_name  = $default_name;
        $actual_email = $email_candidate;
        if (preg_match('/\s*(.+)\s*\<\s*([^@]+@.+)\s*\>/', $email_candidate, $actual_emails) == 1) {
            $actual_name  = $actual_emails[1];
            $actual_email = $actual_emails[2];
        }
        if ($validate) {
            if  (filter_var($actual_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                $valid_arr[] = ['address' => $actual_email, 'name' => $actual_name];
            }
        } else {
            $valid_arr[] = ['address' => $actual_email, 'name' => $actual_name];
        }
    }
    return $valid_arr;
}
```

Should be self explanatory